# Elapsed time column - how to refresh only one part of StructuredViewer

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I have a `StructuredViewer` (in this example a `TreeViewer` with columns) that refreshes its interior through some callbacks I don't want to get into, by calling `setInput()` and `refresh()` on it when the callbacks occur.

I need to introduce a Time Elapsed cell that will need to refresh every second, and this will only be in one cell of the Viewer.

What would be the best way to make a light-weight refresh on only one cell/column?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TreeViewer

```java
public void update(Object element, String[] properties)
```

method is the lightest weight way to update a row.

You can use the 'properties' argument to tell the label providers which column is being updated. The label providers should override

```java
public boolean isLabelProperty(Object element, String property)
```

to tell the viewer which properties they are affected by.

Comment: in the case that ColumnLabelProviders are in use, should this mean that only the LabelProviders that contain cells that need the specific update should override isLabelProperty? Thanks

Comment: They should all override isLabelProperty so they can return 'false' when the property does not require the label to be updated (the default implementation returns 'true' for everything).